# error: passing 'xxx' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    int a, b, c;
public:
    Test() : a(1), b(2), c(3) {}
    const void print() {cout << a << b << c;}
    int sum() {return (a+b+c);}
};

const Test& f(const Test& test) {
    test.print();
    // cout << test.sum();
    return test;
}

main() {
    Test x;
    cout << "2: ";
    y = f(x);
    cout << endl;
}
```

gives the compile error

> "error: passing 'const Test' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers"

?

My `print()` method is `const`, which is all I'd understood was necessary. For me the (commented out) `sum()` method in `f()` should give an error, but not the `print()` method. If anyone can point out to me where I am misunderstanding - that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling a non-const method `print()` on a const object. A `const` method is such that cannot modify the object it's called on, and this is the only sort of member methods you are allowed to call on `const` objects (to preserve the const-ness).
A const method is denoted by `const` *after* the method arguments list:

```cpp
void Test::print() const {
   cout << a << b << c;
}
```

And yes, `const void` is useless at best, just `void` is all the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and helping me see the wood through the trees.

Answer (score 5):

```
const void print()
```

This makes no sense, you meant:

```
void print() const
```

Comment: Cool username, bro:)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Last I looked up, giraffes couldn't talk.

Comment: Violet ones can. Always could. Someone edit the wiki!